# What kind of file I'm dealing with and how to load this into a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, text, character-encoding, endianness, ucs2

I'm downloading this file from an FTP server and when I open it in VIM it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

When I do open this in Notepad++, I see this(looks normal):

[image]

So I tried to see what encoding this file is in and saw that it's in

[image]

Now the problem is that after downloading the file from the FTP I need to load this file into a temp table. How can I safely load this into my table which is in utf8?

When I do the import to my MySQL table it looks like the one below with a space in between the characters:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The temp table can be `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but the connection should be `ucs2` or `utf16le`, I don't know which.

You have not said what your client is, but using `SET NAMES ...` (using one of those charsets) should work with most clients.  Then the conversion will happen as you load the data.

The `ÿþ` (hex `FFFE`) the Byte-Order-Mark.  See [blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark) and links in it.

Comment: Hi @RickJames! thanks man. Is there a way I can get the character set so I can do `SET NAMES ...` dynamically?

Comment: There is no 100% way to look at a file and say how it is encoded.  However, the BOM is nearly 100%.  Suggest you try the two I gave you, and see if the data loads in the table the same.  If not, it may give a clue of which one is correct.